# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing using actix-web

Tags: http, rust, actix-web, rust-actix

Stuck on this problem where I received this error everytime making POST request to my actix-web server.

```
CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing
```

my javascript (VueJs running on localhost:3000) :

```
let data = //some json data
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/abc");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

My Actix_Web server (running on localhost:8080) :

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let cors = Cors::default()
        .allowed_origin("http://localhost:3000/")
        .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
        .allowed_header(actix_web::http::header::ACCEPT)
        .allowed_header(actix_web::http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
        .max_age(3600);

        App::new()
        .wrap(cors)
        .service(myfunc)
    })
    .bind(("0.0.0.0", 8080))
    .unwrap()
    .run()
    .await
    .unwrap();

}
```

my cargo.toml dependencies

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
actix-cors = "0.6.1"
...
```

Got any idea?

Comment: What do the response header look like if you inspect them in the developer tools? Is the header indeed not set, or maybe incorrectly so?

Comment: I'm assuming your Vue.js app does not run on http**s**? That would break CORS also.

Comment: Nitpick: Just use the `fetch` API. `fetch("localhost:8080", { method: "POST", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => /* ... */)`.

Comment: Still the same with fetch API. request header is `"Accept":"*/*`, `"Access-Control-Request-Headers":"content-type"`.

Comment: Those look like the request headers. You should look at the **response** headers :)

Comment: And the fetch API is just more modern and easier to use, shouldn't change anything about the result.

Comment: Got any way that I can bypass the https for dev? :(

Comment: The Vue.js app shouldn't run on HTTPS by default.

Comment: there's not much in response header, only `"content-length":"42"` and `"date": "//time now"` .

Comment: Have you tried using `Cors::permissive()` instead of `default`? I've never worked with the framework, so I can't really say fore sure what it's doing. But according to your comment, the `Acess-Control-Allow-Origin` header is actually missing.

Comment: no improvement with `Cors::permissive()` too. I also tried the `default` with both client and server deployed in the cloud. so both of them is behind https. still got no improvement.

Comment: One thing I missed about the response header is `"Referrer Policy":"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"`

Comment: Update: I tried using `Cors::permissive()` again and it works. Super thankful for that!! Nevertheless, my end goal is to get it working with the `default` method.

Comment: As it would be helpful for you, I'll look into the difference and post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I've done some testing. If you're writing a public API, you probably want to allow all origins. For that you may use the following code:

```rust
HttpServer::new(|| {
    let cors = Cors::default().allow_any_origin().send_wildcard();

    App::new().wrap(cors).service(greet)
})
```

If you're not writing a public API... well, I'm not sure what they want you to do. I've not figured out how to tell the library to send that header. I guess I will look at the code.

**UPDATE:**

So funny story, this is how you allow specific origins:

```rust
let cors = Cors::default()
    .allowed_origin("localhost:3000")
    .allowed_origin("localhost:2020");
```

BUT, and oh boy, is that but juicy. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is only set when there is a `Origin` **request** header. That header is normally added by the browser in certain cases <sub>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin#description)</sub>. So I did that (using the Developer tools in the browser). What did I get? `"Origin is not allowed to make this request"`. I set my origin header to `localhost:3000`. Turns out, the arctix library simply discards that header if no protocol was provided... (e.g. **`http://`**) (I assume it discards it, if it deems its format invalid). That internally results in the header being the *string* `"null"`. Which is, *checks notes*, not in the list of allowed origins.

And now the grand finale:

1. Your origin header needs to be set to (by either you or the browser): `"http://localhost:3000"`.
2. Your configuration needs to include: `.allowed_origin("http://localhost:3000")`.

After doing that, the server will happily echo back your `origin` header in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. And it will only send that **one**.

I've no idea if **any** of that is what the standard specifies (or not). I encourage you to read through it, and if it doesn't comply, please open an issue on GitHub. I would do it myself, but I'm done with programming for today.

Cheers!